# Visual themes in Outlook 2007 addin in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, outlook-2007

1) How can I enable using visual themes in Outlook 2007 addin created in Delphi 7 (using forms)? In Outlook 2003 I create Outlook.exe.manifest, but Outlook 2007 crashed (tested only on Windows Vista) on startup (missing library MSVCR80.DLL).

2) How can I create separator item to menubar? (creating button is App.ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.Item['Standard'].Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 1, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, WordBool(true)))

Thank you, Pavel

Answer (score 2):

ad1) add manifest with two dependecies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"><noInherit></noInherit>
  <assemblyIdentity processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32" name="outlook" version="1.0.0.0">
  </assemblyIdentity>
  <description>Microsoft Office Outlook</description>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50608.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*">
      </assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"><requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I've failed to do that to. Tried to include XPMan unit, adding a manifest to de homedir of my addin dll, but nothing helped.
2. You can try to set the BeginGroup property of the button where you want the separator. I didn't test it, but that should do the trick.